# Drive disappears from `diskutil list` about 35 seconds after showing up

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

When I plug in my 1TB 2.5" SATA drive to my MacBook Air Mid-2013 Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5 machine, the drive never shows up in Disk Utility.

However, the disk does show up in `diskutil list`, along with corresponding disk devices created in the `/dev` directory:

```
$ disutil list
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         800.0 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS                         199.7 GB   disk2s3
```

However, every time after about 35 seconds after the disk devices are created, they disappear until the next replug.

**Why is Mac OS deleting disk devices of a potentially corrupt disk drive?**

I've already rebooted the machine.

Comment: Any resolution here?

Comment: Nope, the drive is malfunctioning. It gets detected on an old Mac, but there's little I can do to restore the data.